# Draw line Paralle in Stage

Tags: actionscript-3

How can I draw the same picture on the other side of the stage as in the following example?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrkXA.png

Here is my code:

---

```
var drawingLine:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(drawingLine);

 stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);


function mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    timer.start();
    drawingLine.graphics.lineStyle(3, coloursArray[position]);
    drawingLine.graphics.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
}


function mouseMoveHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    drawingLine.graphics.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
}

 function mouseUpHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    timer.stop();
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
}


function changeColour(e:TimerEvent):void{
    position++;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `copyForm method` of the `Graphics class`:

> Copies all of drawing commands from the source Graphics object into
>   the calling Graphics object.

General form:

> destinationObject.graphics.copyFrom(sourceObject.graphics);

Your code:

```
var drawingLine:Shape = new Shape();
this.addChild(drawingLine);

var drawingLine2:Shape = new Shape(); // new Shape here
drawingLine2.x = 200;
this.addChild(drawingLine2);

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);

function mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    timer.start();
    drawingLine.graphics.lineStyle(3, coloursArray[position]);
    drawingLine.graphics.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
}


function mouseMoveHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    drawingLine.graphics.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    drawingLine2.graphics.copyFrom(drawingLine.graphics); // copyFrom() here
}

 function mouseUpHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
   timer.stop();
   stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
}

function changeColour(e:TimerEvent):void{
    position++;
}
```